# MDX Cell Calculations - How to parameterize its expression in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, mdx

I have a cell calculation in a query which I use for SSRS query and contains parameter like;

```
MEMBER Measures.[SatisTotalYTD] AS null
CELL CALCULATION ScopeEmulator
FOR '(order(STRTOSET(@Ay1),[DimDateView].[YearMonthNumber].currentMember.name,BDESC).item(0),Measures.[SatisTotalYTD])'
AS [Measures].[KapananAyaKadarTotalYTD]
```

But when I execute the query it gives me error as

> Parameter could not be resolved because it was referenced in an inner subexpression

So I tried to define parameter value as a set;

```
with
SET [Aylar1] as STRTOSET(@Ay1)
MEMBER Measures.[SatisTotalYTD] AS null
CELL CALCULATION ScopeEmulator
FOR '(order([Aylar1],[DimDateView].[YearMonthNumber].currentMember.name,BDESC).item(0),Measures.[SatisTotalYTD])'
AS [Measures].[KapananAyaKadarTotalYTD]
```

Then it gives me

> The definition of the Aylar1 set contains a circular reference.

So how can I use parameter in a cell calculation expression?

Comment: What exact value of @Ay1? Show your parameter dialogue.

Comment: "{ [DimDateView].[YearMonthNumber].&[205],[DimDateView].[YearMonthNumber].&[206] }"

Comment: Do you use the set on Where clause, right?

Comment: No. It's in FOR clause expression.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? what is the end result you're aiming for - I'm struggling to understand this question.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand the Scope conception. You can't do any calculations, all you  can is change the tuple behaviours there. I'm not sure what's your motivation of using ScopeEmulator at all. The fallowing query must do magic considering your code above:

```
With

Set LastTuple as
Tail(StrToSet(@Ay1))

Member [Measures].[SatisTotalYTD] as
IIF(
    [DimDateView].[YearMonthNumber].CurrentMember is LastTuple,
    [Measures].[KapananAyaKadarTotalYTD],
    Null
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I don't want to use "IIF". It is a performance killer. If I rewrite IIF with cell calculation it drops from 3.5 minutes to 4 seconds. But I can not parameterize it to use with in SSRS dataset.

Comment: It's hard to say how to speed up things if you don't show your cube and report structures. Usually the IIF function shouldn't be that slow.